# "Invalid constructor input for Tool" error when using function calling with gemini-pro

Tags: python, google-api, google-gemini

I have the following code to enabling function calling with gemini-pro model (it is based on [this example](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/function_calling_python_quickstart)).

```
def getWordCount(sentence:str):
    return len(sentence.split(' '))


model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name='models/gemini-pro', tools=[getWordCount])

model._tools.to_proto()
```

For some reason, I received the following error:

> TypeError: Invalid constructor input for Tool: <function getWordCount at 0x7a9baaf95c60>

The error repeats for all the following models:

```
models/gemini-1.0-pro
models/gemini-1.0-pro-001
models/gemini-1.0-pro-latest
models/gemini-1.0-pro-vision-latest
models/gemini-pro
models/gemini-pro-vision
```

I could not find any resources to resolve this issue. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78090031

Answer (score 1):

This is how you declare a tool

```
calculator = glm.Tool(
function_declarations=[
  glm.FunctionDeclaration(
    name='multiply',
    description="Returns the product of two numbers.",
    parameters=glm.Schema(
        type=glm.Type.OBJECT,
        properties={
            'a':glm.Schema(type=glm.Type.NUMBER),
            'b':glm.Schema(type=glm.Type.NUMBER)
        },
        required=['a','b']
    )
  )
])
```

It's not just a python function

Comment: based on your example, so it will automatically understand that it needs to multiple a by b? there is no need to add the following `return a * b`?

Comment: No it will tell your application that it needs to run the code you have defined for the multiply function.   I have a video on how to make a chatbot with functions if you're interested